# Clojure - map-indexed is it possible to start with an index other than 0?

Tags: clojure

Usually map-indexed function maps each list item to a respective index where the first index is 0, the second is 1 etc.

Is it possible to have the index start at another number and proceed from there?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You simply wrap the index with another function in the receiving function

For example if we wanted to start at 1 instead of zero we would simply use inc

```
(map-indexed (fn [i v] (vector (inc i) v)) ["one" "two" "three"])
```

Will return

```
([1 "one"] [2 "two"] [3 "three"])
```

Comment: or similarly pass the starting point as an argument to `map-indexed`: `((fn [start-at] (map-indexed #(vector (+ start-at %) %2) "Yechiel")) 6)` => `([6 \Y] [7 \e] [8 \c] [9 \h] [10 \i] [11 \e] [12 \l])`

Answer (score 14):

Easiest way is to just remember that you can pass multiple sequences to `map`.

```
(map vector [:a :b :c] (iterate inc 100))

=> ([:a 100] [:b 101] [:c 102])
```

Answer (score 5):

`map-indexed` does not allow this. However, it's easy to write your own version that lets you do it.

```
(defn map-indexed-from [n f coll]
  (map f (range n Double/POSITIVE_INFINITY) coll))
```

Example usage:

```
user> (map-indexed-from 5 vector [:a :b :c])
([5 :a] [6 :b] [7 :c])
```